# Update few values on few records at once

Tags: sql, sql-update, absolute-db

I'm trying to update values in 2 columns on 2 records at once.

`INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE ... UPDATE ...` doesn't work.

I have read the post about subject but the solution doesn't work for me, so here is my question. Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
[7.4.2017 10:21:07] Executing Query:

UPDATE sales
   SET (ind,otst) = CASE id 
                    WHEN 7795 THEN (759900,2.2)
                    WHEN 7799 THEN (779900,5)
                    ELSE (ind,otst)
                    END
 WHERE id IN(7795, 7799) and recNo>1;
```

Error:

> [7.4.2017 10:21:09] Value is Null - Native error: 30359

P.S. When I change a value in a single column on multiple rows it works fine.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Not all dbms products support those "Multiple column assignment" and "Row types" extensions.

Comment: I'm using embended SQL engine in absoluteDB, so may be it has some limitations. So the SQL code seems OK to you ? if it's ok It may be usefull for others who read this.

Comment: Why can't you call SET ind = CASE ..., otst = CASE ... ?

Answer (score 0):

[7.4.2017 11:33:17] Executing Query:

```
UPDATE sales
   SET ind = CASE id 
  WHEN 7795 THEN 759900 
  WHEN 7799 THEN 779900
  ELSE ind END,
  otst = case id
  WHEN 7795 THEN 99 
  WHEN 7799 THEN 77
  ELSE otst END
WHERE id IN(7795, 7799) and recNo>1;
```

[7.4.2017 11:33:17] Ok.
[7.4.2017 11:33:17]  3 rows affected.

Thank you very much, StanislavL